# Display symbol name from REST API endpoint

Tags: php, rest

I'm trying to extract the "symbol names" from this REST API endpoint:

https://rates.50x.com/market/

```
$fiftyx_coins = file_get_contents('https://rates.50x.com/market/');
$fiftyx_coins = json_decode($fiftyx_coins, true);

foreach ($fiftyx_coins as $coin => $coindata) {
    echo $coindata . "<br>";
}
```

It is just echoing "Array" though.. How can I access the symbol names?

By symbol names, I mean "TAU", "BNB", "OMG", returned by the endpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: `echo $coin . "<br>";` - with symbolnames you mean the "TAU", "BNB", right? That's the keys of `$fiftyx_coins`, so $coin in your foreach.

Comment: After "beautifying" the JSON I see the structure is a little different than I thought, but still not able to access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to correct last part of the code:

```
$fiftyx_coins = file_get_contents('https://rates.50x.com/market/');
$fiftyx_coins = json_decode($fiftyx_coins, true);

foreach ($fiftyx_coins as $coin => $coindata) {
    echo $coin . "<br>";
}
```

When you decode JSON and use `foreach` part you have symbol names in `$coin` and symbol values (an array of name-values) on `$coinvalues`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want an array of the symbols you can use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), then you can implode them to output.

```
$fiftyx_symbols = array_keys($fiftyx_coins);
echo implode('<br>', $fiftyx_symbols);
```

Comment: reciprocated  :)